# configurar @page print css

Tags: html, css

Pessoal poderiam me ajudar com um problema de CSS ( acredito eu ) pois não consigo solucionar sozinho.

conforme print abaixo, ao imprimir a página SEMPRE aparece outra em branco logo abaixo.
[image: impressão com página á mais]

meu CSS

```
 html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
 }
 html, body {
height: 54mm;
width: 101mm;
font: 14px arial, sans-serif;
writing-mode: tb-rl;
 }
 @page {
size: landscape;
margin-top: 0.0in;
margin-left: 0.03in;
margin-bottom: 0.0in;
margin-right: 0.03in;
 }
 .table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <table class="table">
<tr style="height: 95px">
     <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;">
    <div>
         <span>N&#176; A: <strong style="font-weight: 900;">123456789</strong></span><br />
         <span>N&#176; B: <strong style="font-weight: 900;">987456321</strong> </span><br />
         <span>Data Entrada: 18/12/2014</span><br />
         <span>Código: 0000</span>
    </div>
     </td>
     <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;">
<div style="position: absolute; right:-18px;"><img src="code128bar.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle; width:200px;"/></div>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top">
    <div>
         <span>Destinatário: <strong style="font-weight: 900;">FULANO DE TAL</strong></span><br />
         <span>Endereço: AV TESTE 1802</span><br />
         <span>Bairro: TESTE</span><br />
         <span>CEP: 99999-000</span><br />
         <span>SÃO PAULO - SP</span>
    </div>
     </td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Parece que é um Bug do Google Chrome

Comment: @WallaceMaxters pior que no Mozilla também sai 2

Comment: `position: relative` no html??? pode ser o caso de você setar `html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolvido

o problema estava nesse trecho

```
 html, body {
 height: 54mm;
 width: 101mm;
 font: 14px arial, sans-serif;
 writing-mode: tb-rl;
 }
```

Corrigido

```
 html, body {
font: 14px arial, sans-serif;
writing-mode: tb-rl;
width: 381px;
 }
```

Comment: Era a altura? Maior que a configuração da página na impressora?

Comment: Sim @bfavaretto

Comment: @bfavaretto e também pode ser a margem que não foi zerada no `html, body`